# WSO2 - Reset password reports an AuthenticationException in the logs

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are using the ResetPassword API from UserInformationRecoveryService WSDL (https://localhost:9443/services/UserInformationRecoveryService), to request a password reset without captcha for the user 'dummy' with the following body, providing the admin/admin user.

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://services.mgt.identity.carbon.wso2.org" xmlns:xsd="http://beans.mgt.captcha.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
    <x:Header/>
    <x:Body>
        <ser:verifyUser>
            <ser:username>dummy</ser:username>
            </ser:verifyUser>
    </x:Body>
</x:Envelope>
```

The request returns a 200 status code with the token but when checking the console, it reports the following error:

```
Invalid remote address detected.
org.wso2.carbon.core.common.AuthenticationException: Authentication Failed : Invalid remote address passed - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
```

Am I missing any configuration? The WSDL doesn't show any remote address field to send like the login API, so it should be something else.

Or is this log error expected?

UPDATE:

Here are the requested DEBUG logs of multiple wso2 components: http://hastebin.com/ubasixagev.coffee

```
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.user.core=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.application=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.core=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.core=DEBUG
```

Comment: What is the IS version you tried. This is not an expected behavior. Can you explain the exact step to reproduce the issue.

Comment: IS 5.1.0. I use SOAP UI for the specific method, send the request like examplified in the post.

Comment: what is the sevice URL. Are you calling service from a different machine or from the same machine.?

Comment: Same machine. Tested with `https://localhost:9443/services/UserInformationRecoveryService.UserInformationRecoveryServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint/` and 
`https://localhost:9443/services/UserInformationRecoveryService/`

Comment: please enable debugs logs of org.wso2.carbon.identity and org.wso2.carbob.user.core and org.wso2.carbon.core and attach the log

Comment: @IsuraDilharaKarunaratne Post updated. The logs Don't seem to add any useful information.

Comment: are u using clustering. please attach repository/conf foler

Comment: I'm not using clustering. Here is the conf folder: https://1drv.ms/u/s!An0I03NPsIuahJBiVNsbeMe3qeGiuA

Comment: @IsuraDilharaKarunaratne any update?